# AWS with SLES 12 SP 1 registration failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, registration, suse

We have a SLES Suse Linux Enterprice Server on Amazon Web Services.

Since I want to install software I realized that the SLES is not registred.

So I found out to register SLES on AWS with this command:
 `/usr/sbin/registercloudguest --force-new`
src: https://www.suse.com/de-de/support/kb/doc/?id=7022311

Unfortunately this is not successful: `vi /var/log/cloudregister`

```
2018-07-17 11:15:28,679 INFO:Forced new registration
2018-07-17 11:15:28,690 INFO:Nothing to do no registration target
2018-07-17 11:15:28,691 INFO:Using API: regionInfo
2018-07-17 11:15:28,691 INFO:Using region server: 54.244.244.107
2018-07-17 11:15:28,694 INFO:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): 54.244.244.107
2018-07-17 11:15:29,332 INFO:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 54.93.131.24
2018-07-17 11:15:29,341 INFO:Modified /etc/hosts, added: 54.93.131.24   smt-ec2.susecloud.net   smt-ec2

2018-07-17 11:15:29,523 INFO:[Service] No SMT server found, nothing to do
2018-07-17 11:15:29,644 INFO:Writing SMT rootCA: /usr/share/pki/trust/anchors
2018-07-17 11:15:29,646 INFO:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 54.93.131.24
2018-07-17 11:15:29,649 INFO:Updating CA certificates: update-ca-certificates
2018-07-17 11:15:31,087 ERROR:Registration with 54.93.131.24 failed. Trying 54.93.130.182
2018-07-17 11:15:31,088 INFO:Clean current registration server: 54.93.131.24
2018-07-17 11:15:31,088 INFO:Modified /etc/hosts, added: 54.93.130.182  smt-ec2.susecloud.net   smt-ec2

2018-07-17 11:15:31,801 ERROR:Baseproduct registration failed
2018-07-17 11:15:31,801 ERROR:  Error: SCC returned 'Guest verification failed repository access denied' (403)
```